# Unable to Run PowerShell Scripts on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Tags: powershell

I am unable to run PowerShell Scripts on Server 2012 R2 Standard.

When I right-click on .ps1 file and run with powershell, nothing happens.. Powershell screen flashes away and exits.

`Get-ExecutionPolicy` always returns Unrestricted

Can you all guide me if any settings\IT policy requirement that needs to be checked.

An help would be highly appreciated on this.

Comment: Can you run the script from the console and/or ise?

Comment: How do You know, that nothing happens ? maybe add pause on the end of the script so that window does not close as soon as script is executed :)?

Comment: Because at the End of the script i have used powershell.exe. here is my sample script $Machines = Get-Content -Path D:\Rooster\Scripts\ProjectMachinesNames.txt
foreach ($Computer in $Machines)
{
  Get-Volume -CimSession $Computer.Trim() 
}
PowerShell.exe

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code that didn't work. But it looks like you meant `-ComputerName` rather than `-CimSession`.